# Python regex to match after the text and the dot

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, networking, interface

I have to create a regex to find elements after the dot

`interface Bundle-Ether10.20
 interface Bundle-Ether1.1`

In this example only `20` and `1`

I have something like this to match everything before the dot

```
.*(?=\.).
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `(?<=\.).*`  / `(?<=\.).+` / `\.(.*)`...

Comment: Actually, this is not working. But this part of your regex match what I need `(?<=\.).*`

Comment: These are 3 different regexps, and all of them are working and do what you need.

Comment: Sorry then for misunderstanding and thanks for your answer and help